# How to parse PHP array with stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Following is the array with stdClass Object

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Number] => 5
            [Content] => 00666
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Number] => 7
            [Content] => 1018456550591052212900797790669502
        )
)
```

What I want to get value of `Content` corresponding to `Number`

eg. For Number `5` get value `00666`

Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the code for creating that, I am getting confused as to what use as variables!

Comment: I got this array from one of API which has so many children out of only two in example. Here every `Number` is unique and represent  `Content`. Want function if pass value `5` then it will return `Content` value `00666`

Comment: @Snowburnt 's code is working, isn't it?

Comment: Yep its working and also marked as Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this function:

```
function returnContent($myObjectArray, $number)
{
   foreach($myObjectArray as $obj){
      if ($obj->Number == $number)
         return $obj->Content;
      }
   }
   return "number not in array"; //or some other value to denote an error
}
```

call the function something like this:

```
echo returnContent($objArray, 5);
```

or assign it to a variable:

```
$content = returnContent($objArray, 5);
```

just be sure to check if the number existed:

```
if ($content != "number not in array"){ //or whatever value you assigned to denote a failure
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Object properties are case-sensitive, use `Number` and `Content`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function for this:

```
function getContent($needle, $haystack) {
  foreach($haystack as $v) if($needle==$v->Number) return $v->Content;
  return null;
}
```

To use it use:

```
$result = getContent(5, $myArray);
if($result===null) die('Value not found.');
// Use result however you want now
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myObjectArray= myObjectArray() // array of objects

foreach($myObjectArray as $val) {
    echo $val->Content;
}

It will print `00666` and `1018456550591052212900797790669502`
```

Comment: He asked for "Content WHERE Number is $number".